# Aligning column instead of rows

Tags: java

**Magic Garden**

The magic plant above drops two seeds every four years. 
The seeds germinate and by the
following year each turn to a 1-year-old plant.

Something like:

```
Year   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 …
Plants 1 1 1 1 3 3 3 3 9 9 …
```

I need to make a.

 A constructor that “seeds” the garden with some number of seeds.

 A method that returns the number of plants in the garden given the age of the
garden.

 A non-recursive method that returns the age of the garden given the number of
plants.

 A recursive method that returns the age of the garden given the number of
plants.

what I got so far is.

```
   public class test1 {

   public static void main(String [] args)
    {
     String years = "";
     String plants = "";

        int num_years = 30;

        int plant_count = 1;

        for(int i=1;i<= num_years;i++) {
            plant_count = (i%4 == 0)? plant_count * 3:plant_count*1; 
            years = years + i+ " ";
            plants = plants + plant_count+ " ";
        }
        System.out.println(years);
        System.out.println(1 + " "+ plants);

}


}
```

And the out put is:

```
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 
 1 1 1 1 3 3 3 3 9 9 9 9 27 27 27 27 81 81 81 81 243 243 243 243 729 729 729 729 2187 2187 2187
```

The problem I am having is that it prints horizontally, and after the number of plants goes to the triple digits they arent't aligned with the years anymore.

What can I do to make the years in one column and the number of plants in the next?

for example:

```
Years    Plants
1        1
2        1
3        1
4        1
5        3
6        3
```

Ect..

Comment: *"The magic plant **above** ..."*??? There is nothing above!

Comment: @Andreas it's **magic** - that's why you can't see it!

Comment: *"I need to make a ..."* --- 1) *"constructor"* You have no constructor in your code. --- 2) *"method"* You have no method other than `main`. --- 3) *"non-recursive method"* You have no method other than `main`. --- 4) *"recursive method"* You have no method other than `main`. --- How about you **attempt** to write those 4 things before asking questions? --- http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: *"What can I do to make the years in one column and the number of plants in the next?"* Call `println` (or `printf`) inside the loop.

Comment: I am just working on aligning the columns for now.

Answer (score 0):

Try separating them with tabs instead of spaces. That way when you get up to three digits there's sufficient padding between the number sets.